# How to grant the privilege of assigning privileges in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, privileges

I was given access to a database (turtwig) in Neo4j created by a colleage, who gave me the default role 'PUBLIC' and a custom one called 'modeller'. I am  triying to create a new node label but I get this message:
[Node label error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuCnv.png)

When I try to give myself the privilage to create node labels, an error occurs:[GRANT ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WDJQ.png). This same error occurs when I try to grant myself the privileges of assigning privileges with `GRANT ASSIGN PRIVILEGE ON DBMS TO modeller`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and you will see the privileges that user modeller has.

```
SHOW USER PRIVILEGES
```

Granting yourself (as modeller) access for that privilege should be done by admin. Then you should ask your database admin (or colleague) to grant you access to create new nodes.

```
GRANT CREATE ON GRAPH turtwig ELEMENTS * TO modeller
```